# How can write I sql query with rails commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlcommand

My sql command like this. Im trying to relation with two tables. I need the write that query to ruby command with rails helpers.

```
select *, 
  (select branch_id 
   from branches_course_contents 
   where course_content_id=course_contents.id and branch_id=2) as Sube 
from course_contents 
where 
  (select branch_id
    from branches_course_contents 
    where course_content_id=course_contents.id and branch_id=2)=2 
   or show_all_branches=true) 
  and content_type=0
```

My DB schemes:

```
branches
-----------------------------------
id
name:string
active:boolean
..

course_contents
-----------------------------------
id
title:string
show_all_branches:boolean
active:boolean
..

branches_course_contents
-----------------------------
branch_id
course_content_id
```

And model files:

```
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :course_contents
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end

class CourseContent < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :show_all_branches, -> { where(show_all_branches: true) }
end
```

Im trying like this `CourseContent.show_all_branches.merge(-> { joins(:branches) })` but it returns show_all_branches selected and has relation with branches. I actually need show_all_branches selected or has relation with branches.

Comment: what result are you expecting from query at the end?

Comment: I want to merge branch's courses and show_all_branches field selected in courses table but i want to do this rails/active_record helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
    sql = "Select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Or if you are trying to find or count by sql command try this
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html

Comment: Thanks. Actually i mean do that by rails helpers not completely sql commands.

Comment: Tell me what are you writing and what results you are getting and also what is required

Comment: Im writing this `CourseContent.show_all_branches.merge(-> { joins(:branches) })` but its return show_all_branches selected and has relation to branches. I actually need show_all_branches selected or has relation to branches.